# If $f(s) =\frac{s}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}$, how to evaluate $\lim_{s\to \pm\infty}f^{-1}(s)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, inverse-function

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that
$$f(s) =\frac{s}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}.$$

I wrote on my notes during the calculus class that
$$\lim_{s\to +\infty}f^{-1}(s)=1\quad\mbox{ and }\quad \lim_{s\to -\infty}f^{-1}(s)=-1.$$
Looking back, how it is possible to evaluate these limits? Actually, I’m not even able to explicitly compute $f^{-1}(s)$.

Could someone please help me to understand it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: for which values of $s$ does $f$ have vertical asymptotes?

Comment: @JoseAvilez for $s=\pm 1$.

Comment: The second statement probably has an issue. $f$ is defined only on $[0,1]$, while the limit definition would tell you that for large enough $x$, $f^{-1}(x)$ is closed to $-1$, but then this means that for $y$ close enough to $-1$, $f(y)$ is close to $-\infty$, which is expected to hold for an appropriate extension of $f$ : but not for the given $f$ which isn't defined close to $-1$.

Comment: If I set $y = f(s)$ then $y^2 = \frac{s^2}{1-s^2}$ following squaring. If I can make $s$ as the subject of this equation, I can get an explicit formula for $s$ in terms of $y$ i.e. $s = f^{-1}(y)$. Can you figure out how to make $s$ the subject of this formula? (Or is that the part you're having trouble in?)

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_a f(x) = b \iff \lim_b f^{-1}(x) = a$

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer When trying to evaluate s in the equation you wrote, I have $s=\frac{|y|}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$, isn't it?

Comment: @JoseAvilez, did you mean what Essaidi wrote?

Comment: @C.Bishop Indeed, that is correct. Now, the point is that $f^{-1}(y)$ is equal to the right hand side. You can find the limits of that as $y \to +\infty$, for example. It is not correct to use the same logic for $-\infty$, because $f^{-1}$ isn't defined on $\mathbb R$, but rather only on the range of $f$, which is seen to be $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Domain of $f$ should be $(-1,1)$. Please recheck it. $f$ is not defined at 1 and in order to find the limit of $f^{-1}$ at $-\infty$, $(-1,0)$ must be in the domain$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x) = \frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Now, from above it is really clear that the domain for function $\in (-1, 1)$

So, yes I can substitute $x = \sin(t)$ now, here I do not mean that I'm converting the function $f(x)$ to some sort of polar function it's just I'll find the value of $t$ that corresponds to the input of function$(x)$

Say, what is the value of $f(x = a)$ where $ a \in (-1, 1)$
$$f(x = a) = \frac a{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$$
But we can do the same as $t = \arcsin(a)$ and $f(t = \arcsin(a)) = \frac {\sin(t)}{|\cos(t)|}$

$$A = (a, f(a)) = \left(t, \frac {\sin(t)}{|\cos(t)|}\right)$$

- **Solution**

As, the domain of a function is restricted to $(-1, 1)$ you can use the idea of asymptotes;
It means there must exist the constant tend of $y$

$$y = f(s) = \frac s{\sqrt{1-s^2}}$$
$$\implies y' = f'(s) = (1-s^2)^{-\frac 32}$$
$$\implies y'' = f''(s) = \frac {3s}{(1-s^2)^\frac 52}$$
Solve for the value of $s$ for which $f(s)$, $f'(s)$, and $f''(s)$ will tend to $\infty$
Thus, $s = 1$

Comment: Forgive me now only after seeing the graph of $\tan(x)$ I realised my answer is wrong I'll try to edit this answer as soon as possible for me

Comment: #Updated: Let me know if you still find any difficulty in understanding will try to improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the conventional solution suggested by Sarvesh, by observations

WLOG $s=\sin t $

$$f(\sin t)=\cdots=\tan t$$

$\implies $ one of the values of $f^{-1}(\tan t)$. will be $$=\sin t$$

Now let $t=\arctan u\implies \tan t=u,\sec t=+\sqrt{1+u^2}$ considering the principal value of $ u$

$$\implies f^{-1}(u)=\sin(\arctan u)=\sin t=?$$

Notice that for real $u,\sqrt{u^2}=|u|$ and for $u<0,|u|=-u$

Also we actually don't need the explicit value of $f^{-1}(u)$ as we know

$$\lim_{u\to\pm\infty}\arctan u=?$$

Answer (score 0):

First confirm that $f:(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ is bijective (one to one and onto) and continuous. Then $f^{-1}$ is also continuous and since $(f^{-1}\circ f)(t)=t$ for all $t\in(-1,1)$,
$$\lim_{t\to 1}(f^{-1}\circ f)(t)=\lim_{t\to1}t=1$$
and
$$\lim_{t\to-1}(f^{-1}\circ f)(t)=\lim_{t\to-1}t=-1$$
Now since $\lim_{t\to1}f(t)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{t\to1}f(t)=-\infty$ and $f^{-1}$ is continuous,
$$\lim_{s\to \infty}f^{-1}(s)=1\text{ and }\lim_{s\to -\infty}f^{-1}(s)=-1$$